# Microsoft Release Management Server for TFS 2013 - install issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, release-management, ms-release-management

I've been trying to install the new Microsoft Release Management app that has just been released to MSDN and am having issues

It consists of a server side component for TFS 2013, and a client side component for VS2013

The server side component runs through and says that it is installed fine, but then i can't seem to connect the client side part up to it

After a bit of investigation it seems that the web services site that is installed on the server side is not working properly

It is installed on a Windows 2012 box that is also running TFS 2013, SQL 2012, and SharePoint 2013

- If i browse to the newly created ReleaseManagement website I get a 503 (Service Unavailable) message.
- I checked out IIS and the app pool had stopped
- in the application event log I could see a load of messages saying "current configuration only supports loading images for x86 processor architectures"
- I thought this was possibly to do with the "Enable 32-bit Applications" option in the IIS app pool (was set to FALSE)
- I changed that to true and tried the site again. This time the app pool doesn't crash, but I get ASP.NET errors stating "Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ActiveDs' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

Has anyone managed to install this yet? Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

I know it's very new, but I'm struggling to find much information about the product at all

Thanks a lot

Comment: Turn "Enable 32-bit applications" back off for sure. Have you tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it? I installed it for a client a few days ago and it's working great there.

Comment: I have uninstalled it and re-installed with no change but will give it another go

Comment: Uninstalled ... rebooted .. installed. Same issue unfortunately. The Release Management App pool in IIS keeps falling over

Comment: after some more searching I found this [link](http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/sharepoint-error-module-dll-filescommon.html) which runs through a bug with SP2013. I followed the steps in here and it got things running for me

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it! I just passed this article along to a colleague of mine who encountered the same issue, so it's definitely helpful.

Comment: @user2993998 I would recommend filing a bug on connect for this issue if you are facing it on the RTM bits.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link towards some documentation regarding this problem. As pointed out in the comments, it is related to a bug caused by SharePoint: http://support.inreleasesoftware.com/entries/24794668

Interesting section:

> The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable.
>
> This error message usually means that the InReleaseAppPool application
>   pool is stopped. Please ensure that it is started. If the application
>   pool stops after some time by itself, it might be due to a bug caused
>   by SharePoint 2013. Validate your problem by looking at the Event
>   Viewer. Confirm that your error is similar to the following:
>
> Event Log Error Event ID 2282
>
> The Module DLL 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web
>   Server Extensions\15\isapi\spnativerequestmodule.dll' could not be
>   loaded due to a configuration problem. The current configuration only
>   supports loading images built for a x86 processor architecture. The
>   data field contains the error number. To learn more about this issue,
>   including how to troubleshooting this kind of processor architecture
>   mismatch error, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=29349.
>
> We can apply a quick fix using this command
>
> appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/globalModules
>   /[name='SPNativeRequestModule'].preCondition:integratedMode,bitness64
>
> Or you can manually enter the preCondition entry in the
>   ApplicationHost.config file
>
> More information can be found here:
>   http://blogs.flexnetconsult.co.uk/colinbyrne/2012/11/11/RunningA32bitApplicationAlongsideSharePoint2013Problems.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**FIX**:

the user which you specified to run the TFS service needs "**log on as a service**" and "**Log on as batch job**" permissions. I've set that up via **GPO**.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. I execute this command

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/globalModule/[name='SPNativeRequestModule'].preCondition:integratedMode,bitness64
```

in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv` and `C:\Windows\System64\inetsrv`.